# Which one is the right and better way of setting a True value as a function argument

Tags: php, function, arguments, boolean, parameter-passing

Following are two line of code, please observe them.

```
$client->setWatermarkInBackground('True');
$client->setWatermarkInBackground(True);
```

From the code lines you might have an idea that I want to send a value True as an argument. 
But I'm not getting the difference between above two statements. Can anyone explain me the difference between two statements and which one is correct or wrong? If both the ways are correct then which statement is better to use? etc. Please explain me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe just `true` without capitals?

Comment: The first one is a string, the second one is the boolean true. I assume that the statement you are using is working because the function `setWatermarkInBackground` parses the string and evaluates it as true, but the proper way is to not use quotes.

Comment: It completely comes down to the implementation of `setWatermarkInBackground`. The question is as meaningless as "Which is more correct? `func("one")` or `func(2)`?"

Answer (score 0):

```
$client->setWatermarkInBackground('True');
```

You're setting the value *`true`* as a string and not the correct Boolean.

You should set it like this (2nd method) as to set boolean ( 0/1 ).

```
$client->setWatermarkInBackground(True);
```

Allowing you to do something like:

```
if($client->setWatermarkInBackground()) {
    // is true do whatever you need?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most functions you will see in PHP are smart enough to parse strings; therefore, when you pass `"True"` to a function, it will parse it and evaluate it as a boolean value, `true`.

However, this is bad practice and can cause some errors.

If you want to be correct in all cases, do not use any quotes.

```
true --> boolean value
"true" --> string
```

### Edit

According to [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php),

```
var_dump((bool) "false");   // bool(true)
```

Casting from `"false"` to a boolean value will give you a true boolean value, therefore, you must be very careful; remember that the only thing that will cast to a boolean value false is the number 0 or an empty object.

Therefore, in all cases where possible, you should use `true`, with no quotes.

Comment: Note that most functions will treat the string "false" as true as well, since any non-empty string is truthy

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference, since PHP promotes the undefined name `True` to the string `"True"`. You should instead be using the lowercase literal `true`

Answer (score 0):

`'True'` is the string True, in english.
`True` is the boolean value that means true for the computer.

Although PHP is very good and understands both as the computer value, there are some differences:

- When using the test `if ($client->getWatermarkInBackground() === true)`, the first line will return false, because the triple `=` means "Same value and same type", which is not the case, a string doesn't equal a boolean.
- When displaying it with `echo $client->getWatermarkInBackground()`, the second line will return `1`, because it's how the computer understands the value true.

Which one to choose? Well, speak to the computer in its language, it's better, mostly for the programmer who will look at your code (or yourself): if you use `'True'`, I understand you want to display the string, if you use `true`, I understand you want to use it in some test later on.

Answer (score 0):

Any string will always evaluate to true (i.e. a string is a non zero value). Therefore "false" is also true, strictly speaking. Essentially, by using "true", you are evaluating to true almost by luck.

Stick with

function(true) and function(false)

Instead of

function("true") and function("false")